# Will this configuration supply the new gpu (Nvidia RTX 4000 ada) with too much power and damage it?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power, nvidia, nvidia-rtx

I just purchased an Nvidia RTX 4000 and it came with a 16(12+4) pin to 8 pin pcie adapter. Unfortunately it is only 4 inches long. The way my tower is configured it will not reach anything but the existing gpu cable (which was for an Nvidia Quadro P4000).

I installed the new gpu and connected the provided adapter cable to the exsting gpu cable. When the pc was powered on it did not recognize the card. Monitors still diplayed the OS but in old vga resolution. Device manager did not show the new card at all.

After checking connections I discovered that the existing gpu cable is only 6 of the 8 pins at the psu. I am currently working under the assumption that it did not get enough power to the new gpu. All that said, I finally found a cable that is 16(12+4) pins split to 3 8 pin connectors for the psu. I can connect this cable properly with my psu.

**My question is, will this configuration supply the new gpu with too much power and damage it?**

Comment: You can't have too much power.

Comment: A non-faulty GPU will only attempt to draw as much power as it needs. You can't stuff more power into it with, say, a 1600 W PSU. N.B. It could be an issue of the PSU (you didn't tell us the make and model) rather than the graphics card. The maximum power consumption of [that card](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/design-visualization/rtx-4000/) is listed as 130 W, which makes me think it is a PSU issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, will this configuration supply the new gpu with too much power and damage it?

No. "Too much power" could mean either too much voltage or too much current.

For voltage the connector has a standard for which pins get a certain voltage or polarity. Anything that fits the connector should be built to handle the voltage(s) coming through the connector so there is nothing to worry about.

For current (amperage) it is up to the GPU to "pull" the amps it needs to run. The PSU will not force more amperage into the GPU than it actually uses.